# Overriding base class methods in a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monkeypatching, mixins

I'm trying to fool a very complex black box into displaying some floats differently (it's the Gruff graphing library, so this is being rendered to an image).

In the console, I can paste this:

```
  logger = RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER
  logger.debug "Here's a float #{455.67.to_s}"
    eval %{class Float
    def to_s_with_time
      h = (self / 60).to_i
      m = self.to_i % 60
      return h.to_s + ':' + m.to_s
    end
    alias_method_chain :to_s, :time
    end
    }
    logger.debug "Here's another #{455.67.to_s}"
```

And I'll see

```
Here is a float 455.67
Here is another 7:35
```

But if I paste the same code into a controller, I see

```
Here is a float 455.67
Here is another 455.67
```

Why can't I replace Float.to_s within a controller?   I will also accept answers to the question "What's a better way to accomplish this?"

Comment: I wound up adding this (plus an attr_accessor) to the "label" method in Gruff base, which totally works:
      if @is_minutes
        return "#{sprintf('%02i',value.to_i / 60)}:#{sprintf('%02i',value.to_i % 60)}"
      end

However, I'd still like a solution that doesn't involve freezing and then customizing the plugin.

Comment: Why not just create a method that you pass the float to - why do you need to overload Float itself?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the behavior of Float#to_s, you could try adding your monkeypatch to the Float class in an [initializer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializers). This will however patch Float#to_s globally within your Rails app.

config/initializers/float_patch.rb:

```
class Float
  def to_s
    h = (self / 60).to_i
    m = self.to_i % 60
    h.to_s + ':' + m.to_s
  end
end
```

You could also make a similar initializer to patch the gruff classes/methods if you you don't want to be so broad as to patch a core class like Float.

Comment: Interesting, gonna test this later today in rails 4.2